# Page Navigation in Windows 8 XAML (without using code behind)

Tags: windows-8, navigation, winrt-xaml

For my windows 8 application i am trying to navigate between pages with out using code behind. 
For example, i have one image in my UI without creating tapped event for that image i need to navigate to another page,

```
<Image Source="ms-appx:///Assets/Logo.png" Width="155" Height="110" Tapped="{ // Navigation method here }"/>
```

Is it possible to navigate between pages like this...? If possible, how can i get this to work??

Answer (score 0):

XAML is just a declarative language without action part so code behind is an **essential** part of it.
All interactions work via events and event can be handled in a code behind only. So what you want is not possible with XAML(at least with WinRT XAML).

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking if you can specify the code inside the .xaml file, then no, that is not possible.

If you are asking if you can avoid adding code to the .xaml.cs file, then yes, that is possible. You will still need to specify a method but it can even be done as a simple lambda. You will need to use the Command hooks rather than the Event Hooks, e.g.

```
 <Button Command="{Binding GoConnectionCommand}" ... />
```

The code for this command is usually defined in the ViewModel as part of the MVVM pattern, and [Josh Smith explains it far better than I will](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

AlSki mentioned using a ViewModel. Although technically the ViewModel is not part of the "code behind" for the XAML file, it's still code and I believe you were asking for a no code solution.

ixSci is correct that there is no way to do this out of the box without code behind in WinRT XAML.

In full WPF it's possible to do this using a behavior called NavigateToScreenAction. You can read about it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff723957%28v=expression.40%29.aspx). Unfortunately behaviors don't ship out of the box with WinRT, but they can be added back in by an open source project called [WinRtBehaviors](http://winrtbehaviors.codeplex.com/).

There is no NavigateToScreenAction behavior for WinRT, but one could be created. There is a good article on creating behaviors with the library [here](http://blogs.u2u.be/diederik/post/2012/10/28/Using-Behaviors-in-Windows-8-Store-Apps.aspx). It will obviously require code to create the behavior, but after it's created you could use it in XAML without any code.

Really, the short answer is it's not possible to navigate without code on WinRT.

Dev support, design support and more awesome goodness on the way: http://bit.ly/winappsupport